# Function being called multiple times within another is throwing a TypeError: Cannot read property 'suit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined-variable

I'm trying to create a function that checks if two decks of cards are in the same order.

I've written a helper function, cardEq, to test if two Cards are the same, and it works. It does not work in the deckEq function.

```
//Card Struct
//value 1 is ace, 11 is Jack, 12 is Queen, and 13 is King
function Card(suit, value, color){
  this.suit = suit,
  this.value = value,
  this.color = color
}

//Check if two Cards are the same
function cardEq(card1, card2){
  if(card1.suit === card2.suit
     && card1.value === card2.value
     && card1.color === card2.color){
    return true;
  } else {return false;}
}

//Check if two Decks/arrays of Cards are in the same order
function deckEq(deck1, deck2){
  let i = 0;
  let flag = false;
  while (i < 53){
    let x = deck1[i];
    let y = deck2[i];
    if(cardEq(x, y) === true){
      flag = true;
      i = i + 1;
    } else {flag = false; break;}
  }
  return flag;
}
```

I expected it to return either true or false, but instead it throws the error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'suit' of undefined
    at cardEq (repl:2:12)
    at deckEq (repl:7:8)

EDIT: I changed the (i < 53) in the while statement to (i < 52). Thanks for the catch @Christopher and @traktor53. I guess the problem was that the function was calling cardEq on an item in the array that doesn't exist (the 52nd). Since this is meant to compare decks it should only run to the 51st element (the 52nd card).

Comment: Just a thought, the while would be I < 52 since if you’re doing a standard 52 card deck, deck[52] would be undefined as it starts at deck[0]

Comment: How do you build your decks and how do you call `deckEq`?

Comment: @Thomas I have a function that creates an array of Cards, with 52 cards inside. I call deckEq on two such arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As surmised by @Christopher the problem is checking 53 cards in a zero based array of 52 cards inside `deckEq`. Change the while loop statement to

```
  while (i < 52){
```

to see it work correctly with a 52 card deck -

```js
"use strict";
//Card Struct
//value 1 is ace, 11 is Jack, 12 is Queen, and 13 is King
function Card(suit, value, color){
  this.suit = suit,
  this.value = value,
  this.color = color
}

//Check if two Cards are the same
function cardEq(card1, card2){
  if(card1.suit === card2.suit
     && card1.value === card2.value
     && card1.color === card2.color){
    return true;
  } else {return false;}
}

//Check if two Decks/arrays of Cards are in the same order
function deckEq(deck1, deck2){
  let i = 0;
  let flag = false;
  while (i < 52){
    let x = deck1[i];
    let y = deck2[i];
    if(cardEq(x, y) === true){
      flag = true;
      i = i + 1;
    } else {flag = false; break;}
  }
  return flag;
}

function createDeck(){
    const deck = [];
    const colors = ["black", "red", "red", "black"];
    for( var i = 0; i < 52; ++i) {
        var suite = Math.floor( i / 13);
        var value = i % 13 + 1;
        var color = colors[ suite];
        deck.push( new Card( suite, value, color));
    }
    return deck;
}

let deck1 = createDeck();
let deck2 = createDeck();

console.log( deckEq( deck1, deck2));  // expect true
deck2[42] = deck2[0];
console.log( deckEq( deck1, deck2));  // expect false
```

Better yet use the length of a deck array to control the number of while loop iterations, and test the decks have the same length before starting to loop.

Answer (score -1):

`this` inside of a function only works when the function is used as a "[constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)", which requires a `new`instance of the object that the constructor function produces. That's the object that `this` will bind to, otherwise, `this` will bind to `window` and `window` doesn't have a `suit` property.

```js
//Card Struct
//value 1 is ace, 11 is Jack, 12 is Queen, and 13 is King
function Card(suit, value, color){
  this.suit = suit,
  this.value = value,
  this.color = color
}

//Check if two Cards are the same
function cardEq(card1, card2){
  if(card1.suit === card2.suit
     && card1.value === card2.value
     && card1.color === card2.color){
    return true;
  } else {return false;}
}

//Check if two Decks/arrays of Cards are in the same order
function deckEq(deck1, deck2){
  let ceq = new cardEq(x,y); // <-- Need an instance produces by the function
  let i = 0;
  let flag = false;
  while (i < 53){
    let x = deck1[i];
    let y = deck2[i];
    if(ceq === true){  // <-- Use the instance
      flag = true;
      i = i + 1;
    } else {flag = false; break;}
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Comment: `new careEq(x,y)`? cardEq is a simple comparator, no constructor.

Comment: Note the error is that `suite` can't be looked up on `undefined`.  In Firefox it is reported as "card1" is undefined.

Comment: @Thomas `cardEq()` contains `this`, which in a function is used to create instance properties. You can't get instance properties without an instance. So, the function needs to be used as a constructor function.

Comment: @traktor53 The OP hasn't provided all the code that he used to initiate this code, so the fact that you are getting that error simply means that you haven't initiated all the dependent objects the supplied code needs.

Comment: That's `Card` not `cardEq`. But `Card` is not called anywhere in the snippet; neither in yours, nor the OPs.

Comment: @Thomas That's exactly my point. Your error doesn't mean anything because the OP hasn't provided enough code for you to know if your attempt to run his code is valid or not.